# Running Google's DeepDream on Windows with CUDA: ImportError DLL load failed

Tags: cuda, ipython, anaconda, deep-learning, deep-dream

For a deep learning project I am trying to get Google's DeepDream up and running. I followed the steps described here: http://thirdeyesqueegee.com/deepdream/2015/07/19/running-googles-deep-dream-on-windows-with-or-without-cuda-the-easy-way/

My machine:

- windows 8.1 64 bit
- Python 3.4 installed
- NVIDIA Geforce 9600GT
- Installed Anaconda windows 64 bit Python 2.7 version
- Installed CUDA 6.0 because of the older graphics card

I checked the installation of CUDA by running C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v6.0\bin\win64\Release\deviceQuery.exe

This gives the following output:[image]
This seems okay to me?

I extracted the CUDA enabled version of Caffe and the 3rd party addons to the C:/Anaconda directory.

However when I run the first cell of the notebook

```
# imports and basic notebook setup
from cStringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as nd
import PIL.Image
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display
from google.protobuf import text_format

import caffe

caffe.set_device(0)
caffe.set_mode_gpu()

def showarray(a, fmt='jpeg'):
    a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
    f = StringIO()
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-65c745005da7> in <module>()
      7 from google.protobuf import text_format
      8 
----> 9 import caffe
     10 
     11 caffe.set_device(0)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\caffe\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver
      2 from ._caffe import set_mode_cpu, set_mode_gpu, set_device, Layer, get_solver
      3 from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
      4 from .classifier import Classifier
      5 from .detector import Detector

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py in <module>()
     11 import numpy as np
     12 
---> 13 from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver
     14 import caffe.io
     15 

ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
```

I rebooted several times, so that should not be the problem.
When I print the PYTHONPATH that looks correct I think:

> [”, ‘C:\Anaconda\python27.zip’, ‘C:\Anaconda\DLLs’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib’, ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\plat-win’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk’, ‘C:\Anaconda’,
>   ‘c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg’,
>   ‘c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py2.7.egg’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cryptography-0.9.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin’,
>   ‘C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions’]

When I look to the PATH variable the CUDA Toolkit is included.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Previously I had told you your GPU is compute capability 1.0 and requires CUDA 6.  I see now that your GPU is compute capability 1.1, so you could (if you wanted) move up to CUDA 6.5.  Just FYI.  I'm not sure it has any bearing on what you are reporting here.

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with CUDA?

Comment: When using the caffe version without CUDA everything works fine. However, because of speed I want to make use of CUDA. But the caffe version with CUDA causes this problem.